# QGraphicsItem does not show

Tags: qt

I wrote a simple application that displays `QGraphicsPixmapItem`s in a `QGraphicsScene`. The application should be portable without installing Qt on the operating system. I managed to copy only the needed dll files to start the application. Everything works except the `QGraphicsItem`s are not displayed at all, although they are in the scene (wrote a logfile that counts the items).

I figured out that the items are shown correctly, if I copy my "portable" exe file into `Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\mingw48_32\bin` folder. 
The opposite does not work: If I copy all of the `bin`-folder to my portable application folder, it does not work. How can I use a QGraphicsItem in a portable Qt application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason: I needed to add the folder `Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\mingw48_32\plugins\imageformats` to my "portable-app"-folder. In particular, the needed dll was `qjpeg.dll`.

Answer (score 2):

you might miss a plugin for the images you want to display.

make sure your application directory looks like this:

```
<root>
  - <executable>
  - <imageformats>
      - <used image libraries>
```